# on submit button click, execute function then submit form react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering

I have an order form that currently takes a users input and posts it into a dynamo db table on submit.

Right now, that's all the "submit" button does.

I want the on click to instead calculate a price based off of the users input, hide the form, display the price with an "accept and schedule" button, that then posts to dynamo db.

```
      -----------------I am very new to to react js so I apologize if my code is sloppy. -------------------
```

I figured that my function to handle the calculation would look something like the following, as the price is based off of the property square footage in increments of 500.

```
let base_price = 149.99; 
if(sqft > 2000){
  let overage = sqft - 2000;
  let percentage = Math.ceil(overage % 500) * 10;
  base_price += base_price * percentage;
}
```

Now here is my current order form code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { InputGroup, Row, Form, Col, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import LoaderButton from "../components/LoaderButton";
import config from "../config";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";


export default class OrderForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: null,
      streetAddress: "",
      streetAddress2: "",
      city: "",
      state: "",
      zipCode: "",
      propertySqft: "",
      packageSelected: this.props.location.state,
    };
  }

  validateForm() {
    return this.state.streetAddress.length > 0;
    return this.state.streetAddress2.legnth >= 0;
    return this.state.city.length > 0;
    return this.state.state.length > 0;
    return this.state.zipCode.length > 0;
    return this.state.propertySqft.length > 0;
    return this.state.packageSelected.length > 0;
}

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,

    });


  }

  handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  try {
    await this.createJob({
      streetAddress: this.state.streetAddress,
      streetAddress2: this.state.streetAddress2,
      city: this.state.city,
      state: this.state.state,
      zipCode: this.state.zipCode,
      propertySqft: this.state.propertySqft,
      packageSelected: this.state.packageSelected,
    });
    this.props.history.push("/Scheduled");
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }
}

createJob(job) {
  return API.post("dynamodbname", "/prapp", {
    body: job
  });
}

  render() {
    var centerText = {textAlign: "center"}
    return (
      <div className="NewJob">
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

    <Form.Group controlId="packageSelected">
      <Form.Label>
      </Form.Label>
        <InputGroup>
            <InputGroup.Prepend>
            <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroupPrepend">Package Selected:</InputGroup.Text>
            </InputGroup.Prepend>{" "}

      <Form.Control style={centerText} onChange={this.handleChange} plaintext readOnly defaultValue={this.props.location.state} />
        </InputGroup>
  </Form.Group>




  <Form.Group controlId="streetAddress">
    <Form.Label>Address 1</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.streetAddress} placeholder="Property Address" />
  </Form.Group>

  <Form.Group controlId="streetAddress2">
    <Form.Label>Address 2</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.streetAddress2} placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor" />
  </Form.Group>

  <Form.Row>
    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="city">
      <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.city} placeholder="City" />
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="state">
      <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.state} as="select">
    <option value="AL">State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
      </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="zipCode">
      <Form.Label>Zip</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.zipCode} placeholder="Zip Code" />
    </Form.Group>
    </Form.Row>
        <Form.Group controlId="propertySqft">
      <Form.Label>Square Feet</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.propertySqft} placeholder="1234" />
    </Form.Group>


  <Form.Group id="formGridCheckbox">
    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="I agree to terms and services" />
  </Form.Group>

  <LoaderButton
            block
            bsStyle="primary"
            bsSize="large"
            disabled={!this.validateForm()}
            type="submit"
            isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
            text="Calculate Price"
            loadingText="Calculating your price…."
          />
</Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So how would I go about instead the on submit triggers a function that calculates a price based off of the users input, hide the form, display the price with an "accept and schedule" button, and then posts to dynamo db?

If anyone could share either some resources or insight on how I should go about executing this, that would be extremely appreciated!

Images of calculation debugger:

[property sqft is 5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpwrp.png)

[Overage is 3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8InuG.png)

[Percentage is Zero?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/habWf.png)

[when set to 5001 sqft, percentage is only 10?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF1YE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In state, have a value called `totalPrice`, initialized at null, and add a function that get's met before the official `onSubmit`. It could look something like this.

```
checkPrice = () =>{
    //YOUR PRICE EVAL BASED ON USER INPUT
    this.setState({totalPrice: YOUR_PRICE_EVAL})
}
```

In your render, have a condition that says if `totalPrice` then show price and two buttons (`continue`, which will execute form submission, or `back`, which will perform `setState({totalPrice: null})` And reveal the form again.

```
 {this.state.totalPrice ? (
      <div>
        Your price is {this.state.totalPrice}
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Continue?</button>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({totalPrice: null})}}>Back to Eval</button>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <Form onSubmit={this.checkPrice}>
         ...
      </Form>
```

Here is a quick [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-zhukovsky-kt5qf). The code probably doesn't match up 100% with yours but it should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Alternatively you can check out Ant Design's [`Popconfirm`](https://ant.design/components/popconfirm/) component. Basically you wrap it around whatever is going to be clicked (i.e. the submit button) And before it submit's anything the component will render a popup. You can populate the popup with "Your price is..." and calculate the final price. Then pass the props `onConfirm={YOUR_SUBMIT_FUNCTION} onCancel={()=>{this.setState({totalPrice: null})}}`

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight! I was able to display the base price but the calculation seems to not be working correctly so im going to need to dig a little deeper on that. Im not sure if my price eval is correct because no mater the square footage, the price comes up as 149.99

Comment: No problem. As for the calculation I tried it in a code pen by itself and it works so long as the square footage (`sqft`) is greater than 2000. If it is 2000 or less the base price stay 149.99. Where is the variable `base_price` in relation to the `if` statement? Maybe it's out of scope?

Comment: So I was messing with the calculation and found that it returns the orignal base price if its a round number. So if its 5,000 sqft, it will return 149 when it should return something like 187.99. If i do 5001 sqft, it will only multiply the original base price by 10% instead of 30%.

Comment: I added the debugger images to my original post for further explanation! Also didnt mean 30% actually needs to be %60 if its 5000 sqft